# Failure to install Google Cloud Tools on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install Google Cloud Tools on Eclipse after I purchased a new computer and it's just not working. Always getting this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.8.5.202108061424 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group 1.8.5.202108061424)
  Missing requirement: Cloud Tools For Eclipse App Engine Deployment Support 0.1.0.202108052157 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy 0.1.0.202108052157) requires 'package org.osgi.framework 1.8.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse 1.8.5.202108061424 (com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.suite.feature.feature.group 1.8.5.202108061424)
    To: com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy [0.1.0.202108052157]
```

Environment:

1. Windows 10
2. Tried Eclipse Juno, Kepler & Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2021-12
3. I have Google Cloud SDK installed on the machine
4. Java Version 1.8.0_321

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Eclipse 2022-06. Since https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/google-cloud-tools-eclipse states that Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21) is supported, I installed that one, and it worked...

Comment: Having the same problem today.  It's now 2023; you'd think Google could get with the times.  Are we supposed to stay with a version of Eclipse that is 18 months old?  Or is it okay to update Eclipse after installing cloud-tools?

Comment: To answer my own comment question...  "Check for updates" and installing everything caused an AppEngine project created with a working 2021-09 to again be broken even though the main version of Eclipse is still 2021-09 according to splash screen.  I opened a bug against the plugin (though it's probably not the first):  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3706

Comment: Even 2021-09 didn't work for me on Mac. Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse simply refused to install. Refer this issue mentioned here. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3678#issuecomment-1874232797 . The solution suggested in that link is to go further back to 2020-03. It went through successfully!

Comment: Still... Local appengine server refuses to start.